# Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-fbads`

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am inserting Facebook ads in my react native app. I have installed ***react-native-fbsdk-next*** and set up that. I got no issues with this.

Now I have installed ***react-native-fbads*** as per the documentation, but I am getting this error:

```
Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-fbads` from file `Component File`, the package `PATH/node_modules/react-native-fbads/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`PATH/node_modules/react-native-fbads/dist/lib/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? I have tried adding this in metro.config.js

```
resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

go to package.json file of nodemodules/react native fbads and then package. Json and change the main value to the src/index. Js or index.ts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).